# How can I make sure that a user can only edit his own entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Users` that have many `People` that have many `Projects`.

For example, a new project can be created like this:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new(:person_id => params[:person_id])
  @title = "New project"
end
```

How can I make sure that a user can only insert a `person_id` here that really belongs to him?

Answer (score 1):

get user_id from session(server side), but not the parameter (client side), e.g.

```
def new
  @project = Project.new(:person_id => session[:current_user_id])
end
```

or, make the interface more restrict:

```
def new
  @project = Project.create_for_current_user(session)
end

def Project.create_for_current_user(session)
  return Project.new(:person_id => session[:current_user_id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using implicit authorization for this. Your end result should look like:

```
# GET people/1/projects/new
def new
  user = User.find(session[:current_user_id])
  @project = user.people.find(params[:person_id]).projects.build(:title => "New Project")
end

# POST people/1/projects
def create
  user = User.find(session[:current_user_id])
  user.people.find(params[:person_id]).projects.create(params[...])
end
```

Then in [routes.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resources :people do
  resources :projects
end
```

With this approach, the new project will be attributed to the user automatically.

On a side note, you should consider using something like Devise or a before_filter so you can access the current user more conveniently without having to do `User.find` in each action.

And additionally, you should not have an additional @title variable in your controller action. Each controller action should be responsible for sharing a resource or collection of resources.